# Notes is not visible in utility bar

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, notes, utility-bar

Recently i started enabling lightning for an instance, in the process came through utility bar which helps us a lot for easy navigation. But ran into a problem when i try to add Notes component which comes as out of box.

[image: Utility Bar]

But on the layout we are not seeing this notes utility,apart from notes all other utilities are visible on the layout.

[image]

Along with enabling it on utility bar do we need to do any thing more to bring this utility in the utility bar?

Just observed seems to be i have to enable notes in Lightning experience - after enabling this i am able to see notes tab in utility bar, but wondering will it allow us to take any notes or is  it just to see the existing notes as read only.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enable Notes within Lightning Experience for the 'Notes' item to show up in the utility bar. Refer to this article for [how-to](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233687&type=1).

That article might be somewhat outdated, but here what it says (in case that link gets dissolved):

> To turn on Notes within Lightning Experience, follow these steps:
>
> Setup > Setup Home > Lightning Experience > Notes > Set Up Notes >
>   Edit Note Settings > Enable Notes
>
> Going forward, this will be the only way to utilize Notes within
>   Lightning. If this is not enabled, the Notes and Attachments related
>   list in Lightning will only be available for Attachments.  The New
>   Notes feature may also be called "Enhanced Notes" in some
>   documentation which can lead to confusion.  Notes and Enhanced Notes
>   reference the same Feature.

[image]